# Check if a connection with the server is already open - MQTT PHP

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest, mqtt, mosquitto

```
<?php
    $_HOST = 'IPaddress';
    $_PORT = 1883;      // Use port 8883 for SSL
    $_TOPIC = 'topicToPublishOn';
    $_PAYLOAD = $str; 
    $_QOS = 0;
    $client = new Mosquitto\Client("myClient");
    $client->connect($_HOST, $_PORT);
    $client->publish($_TOPIC, $_PAYLOAD)
    $client->loop();
?>
```

I do not want to open a connection every time I call this file. If a connection to the server is already present, I should be able to just go ahead and publish my data.

Comment: so use `include_one()` instead? or check if `$client` already exists, and DON'T initialize it if it does.

Comment: insert this at the top `if(isset($client) && is_a($client,'Mosquitto\Client')) return;` if the hole script should only run once, hopefully you are  including only in global space

Comment: I do not know what is include_one(). If a connection between my server and the mqtt broker is already present, I don't want to open a new connection with the mqtt broker. I dont know how to do this.